# How do I make the home page of the website to come up in the rankings than the internal pages?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, seo, web-crawlers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

Suppose I have a website, e.g. **`www.example.com`** that comes at **number 6** on the Google search rankings. But the internal pages of the website i.e. **`www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2`** or **`www.example.com/index.php`** comes at **number 2** of the rankings. How would I make my prime domain name **www.example.com** to come at the top of the list ? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Suppose if I search "John Conde" for example on Google, I need www.johnconde.com to appear first, and not www.johnconde.com/index.php?a=9 , which at the moment is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google decides what to show 1st based on how its algorithm matches the words that user is currently searching. So if pages `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/index.php?a=1&b=2` show different contents (i.e. the 2nd one shows a 'product X') it might be that Google decided the 2nd one best fit a certain search (i.e. user searched exactly for the words 'product X'), thus it shows the 2nd page prior the home page `www.example.com` of your site. And there is nothing you could do about this.

But by reading the pages' names, I'm afraid the problem you are facing is that both pages `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/index.php` show the same contents. In such a case then you have simply screwed up your site/server settings, and Google gets confused.
You need to create a `301 redirect` on your server to redirect page `www.example.com/index.php` to `www.example.com` and you should be fine (give to Goole the time to reprocess the all thing).

Later on in your site you could also totally replace any link towards `www.example.com/index.php`, with `www.example.com`.